# error 503 using jax-rs service

Tags: jakarta-ee, jetty, jax-rs

This is unusual behavior , I am trying simple jax-rs implementation and it fails .

```
17215 [29943420@qtp-14485739-7] WARN org.mortbay.log - Committed before 404 null
17215 [29943420@qtp-14485739-7] ERROR org.mortbay.log - /CribService/webresources/caas/doesAuthorIDsExist
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Committed
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Response.resetBuffer(Response.java:1024)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Response.sendError(Response.java:240)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Response.sendError(Response.java:342)
```

command :

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: text/plain" -d '2093' http://localhost:8080/CribService/webresources/caas/doesAuthorIDsExist
```

Can someone explain me cause of such error , especially when before restart this service was running without issues

Comment: Did you again try restarting and/or changing the port?

Comment: i restarted the system and this persist , how to change the port , using netbeans

Comment: killed all jetty process and restarted fresh , but this persist

Comment: Just try restarting the machine. That will release all the ports currently being held.

Answer (score 0):

Need to restart the system and kill jetty process and make sure if you re-run and deploy using netbeans , its not deployed out of netbeans .